# How can we use amazon web services for testing purposes [without payments with cards] Closing this question

Tags: amazon-web-services

Closing this question!
Closing this question!
Closing this question!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer-support question, and not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://aws.amazon.com/free/
You have to give your card details while creating the account. Money will only be deducted inly if you cross free tier limit.
Once you are done with testing, close your account.

Comment: Thanks sir , but it asks to for card pin, i think after that money would deduct automatically

Comment: You can provide pin. The money will be deducted when you cross the free tier limit. So be careful while using the AWS service.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Web Services does not offer a "free account". Every AWS Account has full access to the full range of AWS services and there is no distinction between *production* and *test* usage of AWS.

To assist with evaluating AWS services, **new AWS Accounts are given a [Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) of services**. For example, you can run a micro-sized Amazon EC2 instance, a micro-sized Amazon RDS database and store 5GB of data in Amazon S3 each month for the first 12 months of your account without incurring a charge.

However, if you use one of these services in excess of the free usage tier, or a service that does not have a free usage tier, then **your credit card will be charged** for the usage of that service. This is why you are required to provide a credit card when the AWS Account is created.

Often these charges are just a few cents, so it shouldn't deter you if you wish to try services, but be aware of the services you are using and their costs. Also, remember to turn services off (eg EC2 instances) when they are not being used, to further reduce charges.

Answer (score 0):

You can try LocalStack

It's free for try locally so many AWS services

https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30513890)